# Apigility with Doctrine - The creation service never return any entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

I have a little problem. I am using Apigility within Doctrine to do a one project.

But every time I try to get tables in the database to generate the entities, never finds...

[image: =/]

Is there something I forgot to set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what's going on. It was my mistake even imagined by this screen I could generate the entities automatically.
But from what I saw I would have to generate them through the terminal and just select them later on Apigility Admin.

[image]